# How to use Amplify NodeJs SDK to retrieve S3 buckets that belong to a specific Amplify app

Tags: aws-sdk-js

I have several Amplify apps, each with several backend environments. I want to retrieve the S3 buckets that only belong to a specific app and specific environment. I have looked into `@aws-sdk/client-amplifybackend`. I found one method `listS3Buckets` which sounds relevant. But it returns all the S3 buckets under my AWS account. How do I make it so that it only returns the buckets being to a specific app and specific environment?

Comment: Could you filter the buckets with regex based on the environment you want?

Comment: both the app name and environment name are dynamic. The only thing I have is the appId. The goal is to pass an appId to the function and get back only the buckets used by this appId

Comment: Is the `appId` in the buckets?

Comment: `appId` is not in the bucket name, bucket name is in such format `<app name><hash>-<environment>`

Comment: To throw an idea up in the air... You could use parameter store, or Secrets Manager and create a JSON object that stores the different variables (environment, appName), under the appId. Then you could access them. This can possibly be managed by writing `amplify add custom` in the CLI and building the resource with the CDK. I guess this could either be done per environment, or done once in the console. You could even add the ARNs then of the buckets to make things more simple.